# Adding a UNIQUE ID to the URL parameter if the XMLHttp Open Method - What does this mean and how is it done?

Tags: ajax, header, message, unique-id

I need help understanding AJAX. I am going through the tutorial on W3C schools ( creating a button that opens  text file on the server and displays the result in a div)

One part of the tutorials seems abstract to me, without sufficient explanation. I am sure its a pre-requisite that I have missed or not aware of, detailing below

To avoid getting a cached result in response to an XMLHttpRequest made to the server, the tutorial says one needs to ADD A UNIQUE ID to the URL parameter in the XMLHttp Open Method which has been done (in the tutorial) by adding a ?, another character (t) and an  = after the file extention followed by joining a random number to the URL (using  Math.random()). See code below.

A simple GET request would be like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp,true); \\I can understand this
```

Unique ID added to URL

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp?t=" + Math.random(),true);  \\ I can't undersatnd this
```

'?' , 't' &  a random number generator added to demo_get.asp - Why T, why not P Q R Z ?? Why "?" after .asp

Should the compiler not go bonkers and report an error if arbitary characters are added to the file location. How is the part of the URL after the file extention handled as in this case ?t= + Math.random()

This has been a case of much agony and frustration for the last 3 days cause I don't get which part of JS i have missed here, what do you call this concept and where can I read it ??

This apart, specifying message headers while sending data - What are HTTP headers and what do they mean. How do I decide what the parameters of the setRequestHeader() method shall be ?

Please help. Rest of Ajax is clear to me.

(I haven't read on the second part - the message headers. I have asked that query here to avoiding posting another question later, just in case it turns out to be as eluding and enigmatic as the UNIQUE ID concept - Apologies in case its a direct simple question I ought to read up myself)

Comment: That's called a query string.

Comment: If you like it, pick `Q`. It's added to break the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Cache compares the requested URL with those present with it, if a unique id is added to the URL, it does not match and the browser treats it as a *fresh* GET request, which then is forwarded to the server. This is a standard way to bypass / disable browser caching.

Please refer this document for a better understanding of browser Caching.
See Page No 4, which explains the same thing as stated above.

http://www.f5.com/pdf/white-papers/browser-behavior-wp.pdf